# How to get values from all the charts in the tooltip you are currently hovering

Tags: javascript, vue.js, highcharts

I am using Highcharts in the vue.js environment. I use https://www.highcharts.com 7.2.0 and Highcharts-Vue https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-vue#readme 1.3.5.

I have multiple highstock charts in the same page. I am trying to get the values from all the charts into the tooltip of the highstock that I am currently hovering.

Based on this http://jsfiddle.net/mjsdnngq/14/ I am trying to create my code

This is what I have now

vue template

```
<template>
  <div class="vessChart" v-on:mousemove="updateCoordinates" >  
    <v-card :loading=!this.getStreamPlots.done>
      <highcharts ref="chart" :constructor-type="'stockChart'" :callback="chartcallback" :options="options" ></highcharts>  
    </v-card>
  </div>   
</template>
```

This is the "options" as I define it for the chart as a vue data object

```
options: {  
              tooltip: {
                shared: true, 
                pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y}<br>' 
              },
              chart: {
                type: "line", 
                zoomType: 'x'
              },
              title: {
                text: this.streamChart.title
              }, 
              rangeSelector: {
                inputEnabled: false
              },
              xAxis: {   
                ordinal: false,
                type: 'datetime', 
                tickInterval: 5 * 60 * 1000 , 
                labels: { 
                  enabled:false
                },
                events : {
                    afterSetExtremes : this.afterSetExtremes
                } 
              },
              yAxis: {
                title: {
                  text: this.streamChart.title
                },
                labels: {
                  enabled:true
                },
                alignTicks:'left', 
                textAlign:'left',
                align:'middle',
                opposite:false
              },   
              plotOptions: {
                series: {
                  animation: false
                }
              },
              responsive: {
                rules: [{
                    condition: {
                        maxWidth: 500
                    },
                    chartOptions: {
                        chart: {
                            height: 300
                        },
                        subtitle: {
                            text: null
                        },
                        navigator: {
                            enabled: false
                        },
                        legend: {
                          enabled: true
                        },
                        yAxis: {
                          title: {
                            enabled: false
                          }
                        }
                    }
                }]
              },  
              series: [
                { 
                  name: this.streamChart.title,
                  pointStart: 1546300800000,
                  pointInterval: 5 * 60 * 1000 
                }
              ]
            },
```

when the Highstock loads, I use callback, to get it and set it as a local vue var and also push it in an array in the vuex store, so I can have all charts available.

```
chartcallback(hc){
              this.chart=hc;
              this.currentId = this.streamChart.id;
              this.chartData = this.chartData.concat(this.getStreamPlots[this.currentId].data); 
              this.addStreamCharts(hc);  //push it to an array in vuex store
              this.chart.series[0].setData(this.chartData, true, true, true);   
            },
```

and then I use the updateCoordinates to get all the values from all the charts I saved in vuex store, using the searchPoint. Then, feed the values to the tooltip of the chart I am currently hovering

```
updateCoordinates(e){   
              if (this.getStreamPlots.done && this.chart != null) {                 
                let hce = this.chart.pointer.normalize(e);   
                let points=[];
                this.getStreamCharts.forEach(chart => {  
                    let point = chart.series[0].searchPoint(hce, true); 
                    points.push(point);
                });          
                this.chart.tooltip.refresh(points);  
              } 
            }
```

Problems :

1- This works but it shows all the values to the first chart I hovered. For example, I hover to the first chart, I get all the values into the tooltip as I should. But then I hover to the third chart and the values are still showed in the first chart tooltip. No tooltip in the third chart.

2- The values are in different tooltips. I would like for all the values be in one tooltip. (check the image)

[image]
Thank you

Comment: Are you able to reproduce your case on some online editor which I could work on? You can use this template: https://codesandbox.io/s/nw750l07nj

Comment: @SebastianWędzel Thanks. I will try to reproduce and send you a link

Comment: @SebastianWędzel Please check this. For some reason it does not work but it will give you a general idea of what I am trying to do and how the vue-highcharts are related [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-r5jo0)

Comment: Highcharts-vue supporter will take care of your case. This thread will be continued on the Highcharts forum - https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=43165&p=152292#p152292